# CocoaPodspec unresolved identifier error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to create my own framework by CocoaPodspec.
I need some help to resolve the issue.
And I got an error after run command `pod lib lint --no-clean --verbose` interminal :

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'GlobalLoaderView'
```

This is Podspec file content :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.platform = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
  s.name = "HalBase"
  s.swift_version = '4.0'
  s.summary = "This is example"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.version = "1.0"
  s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author = { "ntancnit@gmail.com" => "ntancnit@gmail.com" }
  s.homepage = "https://github.com/ntancnit/HalBase"
  s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/ntancnit/HalBase.git", :tag => "#{s.version}"}
  s.ios.framework = "UIKit"
  s.ios.framework = "CoreLocation"
  s.ios.framework = "Foundation"
  s.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0.0'
  s.dependency 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.0.0'
  s.dependency 'RxDataSources', '~> 3.0'
  s.dependency 'Action'
  s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  s.dependency 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.0'
  s.dependency 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.0'
  s.dependency 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 5.0.0'
  s.dependency 'SVProgressHUD'
  s.dependency 'PureLayout'
  s.dependency 'KeychainAccess'
  s.source_files = "HalBase/**/*.{swift,h,m}"
  s.resources = "HalBase/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,plist,swift}"
end
```

GlobalLoaderView is my custome class inhered from UIControl.
I am using swift 4, Xcode 9.4

Thank you!

Comment: sorry about 
inconvenience, this error I got when I run command "pod lib lint --no-clean --verbose" in terminal

Comment: Where is `GlobalLoaderView` in the file hierarchy?

Comment: I resolved the issue, the root cause that : 
I define the resources file from path : s.source_files = "HalBase/**/*.{swift,h,m}"
but the file "GlobalLoaderView" was referent from another project.
So pod build can't find this file.
resolve by remove the referent, add copy this file to project, after that, add this file with new path.